# Websockets load balancing with HAProxy

Tags: websocket, kubernetes, haproxy, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to configure an HAProxy ingress controller to load-balance properly connections to websocket. I tried to raise the value timeout-client, timeout-server and timeout-connect but without success.

**ingress.yaml**

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: test-deploy
  name: app-test
  labels:
    app: app-test
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    ingress.kubernetes.io/timeout-connect: "5000"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/timeout-client: "5000"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/timeout-server: "5000"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/timeout-tunnel: "3600"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: k8s-test.local.lan
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /app-test
            backend:
              serviceName: app-test
              servicePort: 9000
```

Comment: Could you check if you can successfully connect with websocket client directly to the pod and to the service app-test ClusterIP:9000?

Comment: @VAS Yes, I can, I tested. HAProxy receive a HTTP request with “Upgrade: websocket” header, but service app-test does not receive request with this header. It seems to me that the HAProxy does not recognize websocket.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found confirmation about websockets support in the HAProxy documentation, but [this post](https://www.quora.com/Does-haproxy-support-websockets) on Quora stated that it works great. You may need to adjust client/server/tulnnel timeouts and sometimes match and route websockets traffic to the correct backend destination.

You can check actual haproxy-ingress confgiration using the following command:

```
kubectl exec -ti haproxy-ingress-pod-name -n ingress-controller -- cat /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

If you have more than one ingress in the cluster you may need to specify a proxy class in the annotation for every Ingress object that should be used by HAProxy ingress:

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "haproxy"
```

HAProxy ingress is pretty much the same HAProxy with the capability to use Kubernetes Ingress objects to update it's configuration.
You can find more information about configuring HAProxy and HAProxy Ingress in the articles:

- [Websockets Load Balancing with HAProxy](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/websockets-load-balancing-with-haproxy/)
- [Using HAProxy as an API Gateway, Part 1 [Introduction]](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/using-haproxy-as-an-api-gateway-part-1/)
- [Haproxy Ingres](https://github.com/jcmoraisjr/haproxy-ingress)
- [Voyager](https://github.com/appscode/voyager)

Hope it would be helpful to you.